# What Audio Stream flag to set to adjust chromecast volume

Tags: android, chromecast

I am attempting to adjust volume of the chromecast receiver using MediaSessionCompat.

Here is the code that initiates the MediaSessionCompat

```
    ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, RemoteControlReceiver.class.getName());
    Intent remoteControlIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    remoteControlIntent.setComponent(receiver);
    PendingIntent mediaPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, remoteControlIntent, 0);
    mediaSession = Optional.of(new MediaSessionCompat(context, MEDIA_SESSION_TAG, receiver, mediaPendingIntent));
    mediaSession.get().setMetadata(
            new MediaMetadataCompat.Builder()
                    .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, mediaDelegate.getTitle(this))
                    .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ARTIST, resources.getString(R.string.casting_to, adapter.getDeviceName()))
                    .putBitmap(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART, adapter.getMastheadImage(screenSize.x, screenSize.y)).build());

    mediaRouter.setMediaSessionCompat(mediaSession.get());
    mediaSession.get().setPlaybackState(getBasePlaybackStateBuilder().setState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING, 0, 0).build());
    mediaSession.get().setFlags(MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS | MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS | VolumeProviderCompat.VOLUME_CONTROL_ABSOLUTE);
    mediaSession.get().setActive(true);
    tokenPublisher.onNext(mediaSession.get().getSessionToken());
    mediaRouter.addRemoteControlClient(mediaSession.get().getRemoteControlClient());
```

Code that attempts to set the volume of the chromecast receiver

```
MediaControllerCompat mediaControllerCompat = new MediaControllerCompat(getContext(), token);  // Token that the media session generates
float maxVolume = mediaControllerCompat.getPlaybackInfo().getMaxVolume();
mediaControllerCompat.setVolumeTo((int) ((seekBar.getProgress() / 100f) * maxVolume), 0);
```

When I do this, it changes the Music Stream volume as its set to the default

I am aware that I can set the volume using `Cast.CastApi.setVolume(2);` but the issue with this is that it does not show the volume progress bar on the reciever like it does when you adjust with the hardware buttons.

I'm not sure how to set the volume stream the MediaSessionController changes. There doesnt seem to be any documentation on this. I know this is possible as Netflix does this.

Here is an example of Cast.CastApi.setVolume not showing the receiver UI
https://www.dropbox.com/s/uvjtma26luem32b/20150515_113421.mp4?dl=0

This is UI that comes up when the hardware buttons are used
https://www.dropbox.com/s/psk1g314puz9ie4/20150515_113313.mp4?dl=0

The code used to set the volume programmatically is `messageStream.get().setStreamVolume(googleApiClient.get(), volume);`

Thanks!

Comment: Cast.CastApi(apiClient, volume) does set the volume on the receiver side and it does show the progress bar on the receiver screen.

Comment: @AliNaddaf I can confirm that Cast.CastApi(apiClient, volume) does not show the Volume UI. Is there any flags that I need to set?

Comment: @AliNaddaf I edited the post to show examples of what happens when setVolume is used

Comment: I am not sure I understand what this is: "messageStream.get().setStreamVolume(googleApiClient.get(), volume);", it seems to me it is changing the "stream" volume and that is different from changing the "device" volume; in terms of the Cast SDK, you have RemoteMediaPlayer.setStreamVolume() which you should avoid using (and doesn't show a seekbar on screen) and there is Cast.CastApi.setVolume() which is the right one to use and that shows the seekbar on the receiver side.

Comment: Ah you are  correct.  Sorry for the confusion.